# Azure - Create Database via HTTP API (using Secret) - 403 Error

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to create an Azure Database programmatically using C# via the [HTTP API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databases/createorupdate#code-try-0).

I found [this resource](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2018/09/27/how-to-securely-connect-to-azure-from-c-and-run-rest-apis/) (in which he uses App Secret, rather than certificate), but can't get it to work due to a 403: Forbidden error.

If I use the token created in the ['try it'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databases/createorupdate#code-try-0) section of the azure docs, the code works fine, so it must be that the token generated doesn't have the permissions I need.

The secret I am trying to use was generated in Portal > Active Directory > App Registrations > {myapp} > Certificates and Secrets.

In API permissions I've added just about everything - though please suggest any I might have missed!

I opened the firewall to my IP and have spent hours looking for the answer, but can't seem to figure it out.

What am I missing please?

Although I believe it's permissions somewhere in Azure, here's my code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Create a new database
/// </summary>
/// <param name="subscriptionId">See Portal > Subscriptions (pick the right subscription!)</param>
/// <param name="resourceGroupName">The resource group the server was created in</param>
/// <param name="locationName">e.g. UK (South)</param>
/// <param name="sqlServeName">The name of the SQL Server VM created when the first database was created</param>
/// <param name="tenantId">See GetAccessToken</param>
/// <param name="clientId">See GetAccessToken</param>
/// <param name="clientSecret">See GetAccessToken</param>
/// <param name="databaseName">The name of the database to be created</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private async Task CreateDatabaseAsync(string subscriptionId, string resourceGroupName, string locationName, string sqlServeName, string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret, string databaseName)
{
    var token = await GetAccessTokenAsync(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

    var url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/" + subscriptionId + "/resourceGroups/" + resourceGroupName + "/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/" + sqlServeName + "/databases/" + databaseName + "?api-version=2017-10-01-preview";

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    string requestBody = "{location: \"" + locationName + "\"}";

    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PutAsync(url, new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
    var statusCode = response.StatusCode.ToString();
}


/// <summary>
/// Gets and access token with which to call the Azure API
/// </summary>
/// <param name="tenantId">See Portal > Active Directory > Properties > Overview for this value</param>
/// <param name="clientId">See Portal > Active Directory > App Registrations > This App > Overview for this value</param>
/// <param name="clientSecret">See Portal > Active Directory > App Registrations > This App > Certificates & Secrets > Generate Secret </param>
/// <returns></returns>
private async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Begin GetAccessToken");
    string authContextURL = "https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId;
    var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContextURL);
    var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
    var result = await authenticationContext
        .AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", credential);
    if (result == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
    }
    string token = result.AccessToken;
    return token;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find the answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52865993/852806)/ this [Microsoft Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application).

What I needed to do was:

1. Go to Portal > Subscriptions > {my subscription}
2. Click on Access control (IAM)
3. Add > Add Role Assignment as shown below (note: 'SqlTest' is the Application I created in Portal > Azure Active Directory > App Registrations)

[image]

Then the code works nicely.

Comment: Hi, you can accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: @LeonYue. I will. You have to wait 48hrs to do so, so I can't do it yet. Thanks. J